# Xamarin Forms ListView ViewCell with Picker SelectedIndex set to -1 on scroll and SelectedItem set to null

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview with  ViewCells that contain Picker. I set SelectedItem in the viewcell, but when scrolling the listview the selectedindex is set to -1 internally by the picker and  the selectedItem is set to null. Does anybody had similar problem?

Cell view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="Calderys.Core.Pages.Documents.DocumentsListItemView">
    <StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Calderys.Core.Pages.Documents.DocumentsListItemView"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!-- Language picker -->
        <Picker 
            HeightRequest="40"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
            Margin="0,10,0,10"
            Title="Select language"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage.Value}"
            x:Name="LanguagePicker"
            />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

ViewModel Behind single list view item code part:

```
public DocumentBaseListItemViewModel(
    DocumentItemModel source,
    INavigationService navigationService)
{
    Item = source;
    _id = source.Id;

    /*
     * Services
     */
    _navigationService = navigationService;

    /*
     * Collections
     */
    if (Item.Pdfs != null && Item.Pdfs.Count > 0)
    {
        Languages = Item.Pdfs.Select(x => new KeyValueDtoModel { Key = x.LanguageCode, Title = x.Language }).ToObservableCollection();
    }
    else if (Item.LocalPdfs != null && Item.LocalPdfs.Count() > 0)
    {
        Languages = Item.LocalPdfs.Select(x => new KeyValueDtoModel { Key = x.LanguageCode, Title = x.Language }).ToObservableCollection();
    }

    /*
     * Properties
     */
    SelectedLanguage = new ReactiveProperty<KeyValueDtoModel>();
    SetSelections();
}

public void SetSelections()
{
    if (Item.LocalPdfs != null && Item.LocalPdfs.Count() > 0 && Languages != null && Languages.Count() > 0)
    {
        SelectedLanguage.Value = Languages.Where(x => x.Key == Item.LocalPdfs.First().LanguageCode).First();
    } 
}
```

List View Xaml Code:

```
<ListView 
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <documents:DocumentsListItemView />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem occurs when caching is set for the ListView to RecycleElement or RecycleElementAndDataTemplate.

Comment: _Code! code! code! We can't create bricks without clay!_

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sorry that I have not put any code, but I was thinking of a problem as something general. I have put some code. Thanks.

Comment: Oddly enough, people on Stackoverflow are almost completely incapable of "something general".